# change the pop up message text after we click on "shipping method"

Tags: shipping-methods, popup

we are not able to deliver the products to the some locations/pin/zip code.

so we want to restrict customers to order the product to those locations/pin/zip code
We are using Table rates shipping method. We entered all the zip/postal codes we deliver the products in an excel sheet (see image)

= > tablerate.csv and uploaded in magento table rates shipping method.

so when customer click on "shipping method" we are getting pop up message as in the image.

But we want to change the POP UP message text. How do we change the message in the popup?Please help me to find location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is found in /app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv

OR go to

skin/frontend/base/default/js and download your files onepagecheckout.js and onepagecheckout.pack.js

On file onepagecheckout.js go to line 404 and correct “neccessary for necessary you will see it has 2 “C’s” now search on onepagecheckout.pack.js for the word neccessary ...  and correct that one..

And finally edit your locale .csv and add at the end..  in my case was OnepageCheckout.csv

“Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.","your translated text”

Comment: it is not there, are you sure it will be there?

Comment: here we have this message " This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: i changed here : /app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv but did't work, i will try the second one....

Comment: seems this problem is coming from excel sheet pattern....

Comment: hi, actually the pop up box is not visible if we use another excel format. seems there is some problem with excel sheet.

please check the updated image in question.....

Comment: But i thought you want to change the text in the popup or not? Maybe you should fill out the country

Comment: i got it, it's from excel sheet, but before if i did't put country id , than also it was working.....